# Ignoring .blendX files in gitignore

Tags: gitignore

I'm making a game for a Gr. 12 programming course with my friends. I have 3D models I made in Blender on my local repository. Blender files end in `.blend`, and it also likes to make backups with extensions such as `something.blend1`, `something.blend2`, and so on, and I don't like deleting them every time I work on them. I'd like to ignore those in my `.gitignore`, how would I do that?

I tried having `*.blend*` in my `.gitignore`, but that ignored everything that ended in `.blend`. I also tried `.blend*`, but that ignored nothing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this instead: `*.blend?`

The `*` matches zero or more characters, but the `?` matches a single character.

Comment: Or *.blend[0-9] to ensure that only numbers are considered.

Comment: @Kay: This does not work. gitignore files do not support arbitrary regular expressions.

Comment: @LukasBoersma the following line is of my .gitignore and it works, I jsut tried it out: Assets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains/*.[Dd][Ll][Ll] Any .DLL is ignored but if I change it to .DL it shows up as new file to be added

Comment: I just tried this, "*.blend[0-9]" works too for me. GIT version 2.25.1